# Ember.js: Controller dependency in nested routes failing

Tags: ember.js

I am just starting with ember.js (v1.7.0) and I have the following routing configuration:

```
this.resource('customer', { path: '/Customer/:id' }, function () {
    this.route('employees', { path: '/Employees' });
}
```

I am trying to define in employees controller the dependency to customer controllers like this:

```
App.CustomerEmployeesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: "customer",
    customer: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.customer')
}
```

However, customer is always `undefined`. Using `this.controllerFor('customer')`, works as expected.
Here is a jsbin to illustrate this: http://jsbin.com/jifiqe/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a few things wrong with your code. When fixed, it seemed to work OK for me.

1. `needs` should be an array of strings, not just a string.
2. Your JSBin left the `s` out of `CustomerEmployeesController`.
3. You use `customer.id` in your property, but that doesn't refer to anything. There is no implicit `this` in Javascript, and especially not in Ember. You have to use `this.get('customer.id')`.